# return 2 values in a function and get the 2 values in another function in the same class

Tags: php, mysql

I need calculate the percentage of 2 values ​​and whether up or down on an arrow.
okay so I created two functions to verify, arrow and percentage that are.

```
private function porcentagem($a,$b){
        $re = $b * 100 / $a;
        return print round($re,0)."%";
}

private function seta($a,$b){
    if($a < $b){
      return "up";  
    }else{
      return "down";    
    }
}
```

I created a function that returns the data to an array, to become more organized.

```
private static function retornar($a,$b){
return array($a,$b);    
}
```

Now the function that checks the data for category :

```
private function new_user(){
        $q       = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usu4r10s WHERE premium IS NULL AND " . $this->antes);
        $a = mysql_num_rows($q);

        $q       = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usu4r10s WHERE premium IS NULL AND " . $this->depois);
        $b = mysql_num_rows($q);

        return self::retornar($this->porcentagem($a,$b),$this->seta($a,$b));
}
```

remembering that "antes" and "depois" is a variable to become more organized.

```
var $antes = "DATEDIFF(NOW(), `data`) < 30";
var $depois = "DATEDIFF(NOW(), `data`) < 0";
```

now the final function I'm having problems.

```
public function _build(){
      $output =   
           '             <span class="mws-report-content">'.
           '                <span class="mws-report-title">Novos Usuários</span>'.
           '                 <span class="mws-report-value '.$this->contas_premiuns(array(0)).'">'.$this->contas_premiuns(array(1)).'</span>'.
           '             </span>';

           try{ 
           return print $output;
           }catch (Exception $e){ 
           return print $e;
           }
}
```

the only problem is that I do not know how to return 2 values ​​in a function.

Comment: Returning two value isnt possible. But changing two poperty value are allowed. Try that instead

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should never use `return print(...);` since that will just return the result of the print statement, which is almost always `true`. Second, it is not very good design to return multiple values from the same functions, a function should generally have a single purpose.

You can not have two return statements after each other, since PHP will exit the function when the first return statement is encountered. If you really want to return two values from a function you would have to use the same method you've used in the code you posted, `return array($firstValue, $secondValue);` or even `return array('firstIdentifier' => $firstValue, 'secondIdentifier' => $secondValue);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can return only **one** (or no) value from a function call but the value you return could be an array or object. So

```
return array($value1, $value2);
```

would return a numerical array with two values.

```
return array('key1' => $value1, 'key2' => $value2);
```

would return an associative array with two values.

```
$instance = new stdClass();
$instance->key1 = $value1;
$instance->key2 = $value2;
return $instance;
```

would return an object of standard class with two values.

**BUT...**

Although these examples would allow you achieve your desired result, as best practice, consider refactoring you function(s) to return only one actual value.